# Wordpress plugin to integrate site search filters?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, web-deployment-project, woocommerce-bookings

I am a newbie to Wordpress and PHP, I want to write a plugin which will integrate search filters on my website, e.g.

search by availability date (this is the filter I want to create and integrate with other filters) such as -
search by location and
search by price (low to high etc).

there are many filters on my website search page, but they are not integrated yet, for example I want to create this filter search by availability date and then use it in conjunction with filter by location, I want to integrate these filters.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction for how I can do that in Wordpress?

FYI I am using a listify theme for my website....

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome.  Note that "wanna" is slang, doesn't really work in a sentence... should be "want to"....

Comment: Hi Harjeet, welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the sample code you have tried writing so far. Have you tried anything? We need a minimum, complete, and verifiable example to work with.

Comment: @cale_b you could have done an edit instead of that comment

Comment: so I am just learning to write a plugin for wordpress, so I have got pretty puch nothing here....once again my website is thecasatimes.com, so I have used various plugins to make this website function....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @YvonneAburrow - it's lovely you went ahead and did it.  Had I _done_ it, OP may not have seen / understood what / why it was changed.  Instead, I chose to _teach_, rather than to _give_.  But again - great that you did it!

Comment: @cale_b OK fair enough